Auto-completion not working when templates are moved to a directory different than "templates";
I currently have my .html templates in "/resources/static" instead of "/resources/templates":
enter image description here
Unfortunately, as you can see on the screenshot - Thymeleaf does not recognize any of the model attributes, or any of their fields.
Additionally - I do not get any auto-completion when I try to use the "." on a specific model attrivute.
The moment I move the template in "/resources/templates" - everything works properly:
enter image description here
The Spring boot application works properly without absolutely any problem.
The issue is that it is very annoying to code with 0 Auto-completion help from IDE's end.
Does any of you have any solution?
Kind regards,
I've already checked the settings in IntelliJ, but I could not find anything that solves the issue.

I would advice against doing that change. By putting the templates in the static folder, they become accessible as raw html, which is probably not want you want. Why specifically do you want to do this?

It seems bugs in IDEA similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-253694/Unable-to-relocate-thymeleaf-templates, I suggest you provide some sample project at the issue and reopen the issue.

@WimDeblauwe - "...they become accessible as raw html, which is probably not want you want. " - before I read your comment, I was not aware of the fact that this could cause any problems. I will research the topic in details. Thank you :bow. The reason I put all templates in the "static" directory is because I generated my font-end using Webflow. When I have the templates in "templates" I have to deal with tons of headakes in order to make the CSS classes created by Webflow work properly.
JackyLiu - thank you a lot. Maybe I will do it in the future :bow
